# Несколько сот или несколько сотен?

Tags: грамотная-речь

На одном из форумов было сказано: "Количественное числительное "сто" согласно современным морфологическим нормам русского литературного языка не употребляется в такой архаичной форме "сот".

Это действительно так?

В современном языке это числительное имеет две формы: сто и ста. Но выражение "несколько сот" употребляется довольно активно, и тогда возникает вопрос: в каких источниках определяется его нормативность, есть ли стилистические ограничения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Сот, стам, стами, о стах**, родительный, дательный, творительный и предложный падежи множественного числа (форм именительного и винительного падежей множественного числа и форм единственного числа нет). Употребляется преимущественно с числительным несколько.

Краткий словарь трудностей русского языка Н. А. Еськовой:

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за ответ. Я еще решила посмотреть в учебниках. Например, в "Морфологии современного русского языка" 2009 года эти формы вообще не упоминаются. В Грамматике-80 слово "сто" в этом случае считается существительным, как и сотня, а потом говорится о применении падежных форм, причем с ограничениями. Они как бы относятся  только к деньгам, сочетание " в нескольких стах письмах" ненормативно.

Comment: Вот примеры из корпуса: Тогда молодой наркоделец продал заезжему курьеру пробную маленькую партию в несколько сот граммов [Екатерина Ерошкина. Прикрыта гашишная заготконтора. (2003) // «Ежедневные новости» (Владивосток), 2003.01.15]Такой завод занимает площадь 100 тыс. м 2, и работает там несколько сот человек. [Петр Меньших, Владимир Каданников. В Тольятти придут инвесторы… (2003) // «За рулем», 2003.05.15]

Comment: Несколько сот человек погибли под огнём солдат, были растерзаны толпой десятки офицеров и полицейских. [Юрий Гуллер. Русский бунт, демократический, но беспощадный (2002)Магазинам среднего масштаба, оборот которых не столь велик, чтобы рассчитывать на серьёзные скидки у курьерских служб, есть смысл объединять заказы, например, в рамках торговых площадок, на которых порой размещаются по несколько сот магазинов: torg. ru, tovar. yandex. ru, podbery. ru, deshevle. ru, webmarket. ru. [Ирина Шувалова. Шаг назад и два вперед (2001) // «Эксперт-Интернет», 2001.03.12]

Comment: Серж, И.-В.падежи применяются часто, а вот остальные как?

Comment: Это может дать такое же понятие о рельефе дна океана, как прогулка слепого великана, шаг которого равен ***нескольким стам*** километрам: он перешагнет через Уральский хребет, даже не заметив его, и будет продолжать думать, что гуляет по гладкой, как стол, великой европейско-азиатской равнине. [Григорий Адамов. Тайна двух океанов (1939)]

Comment: Старый текст, может, потом правило изменилось?

Comment: Это правило? Слово сто в значении существительного ('количество 100', 'сотня') употребляется только в косв. пад. мн. ч. обычно в сочетании с числ. много и несколько: род. п. сот (несколько сот рублей), дат. п. стам (нескольким стам рублей), тв. п. стами (редко: с несколькими стами рублей), предл. п. о стах (Напечатано много сведений о нескольких стах деятелей. И. Грабарь).

Comment: Встречающиеся сочетания типа в нескольких стах письмах (газ.); в нескольких стах метрах (Симон.), в которых сто не управляет существительным, а согласуется с ним в падеже (т. е. выступает как числительное), не нормативны. В подобных случаях рекомендуется употреблять формы сущ. сотня: в нескольких сотнях писем, в нескольких сотнях метров. То есть конструкции c р. п. сот (несолько сот) легитимны, а с другими формами (в нескольких стах) -- нет.

Comment: Ну да, понятно, "сто" здесь  нельзя считать числительным, это существительное. А ваш пример разве правилен: "шаг которого равен нескольким стам километрам", здесь же соласование, а не управление.

Comment: @Arina Мне кажется, что _правильно_ должно быть так (управление род.падежом): "...шаг которого равен нескольким стам _километров_..."

Comment: Да, спасибо, я как раз это имела в виду.  Знаете, что меня огорчает в наших  учебниках, так это отсутствие ясного и понятного  объяснения. Вот сказали бы так:  кроме числительного "сто", есть существительное "сто"  с тем же значением, что и сотня. Это существительное имеет только  формы косвенных падежей мн. числа, которые используются в сочетаниях со словами несколько, много. Важно помнить, что сущ. "сто"  (то есть его разрешенные формы) УПРАВЛЯЕТ Р. падежом следующего за ним сущ.  (равен  нескольким стам километрОВ), а не согласуется с ним ( (равен  нескольким стам километрАМ - это неправ.!)

Comment: Arina,да, возможно тогда эти формы были разрешены, потому что и не было строгих правил. Вы правы: объяснение в грамматикак размыто.

Comment: Честно говоря,  я про сущ. "сто"  не слышала. У Кузнецова в словаре  эта тема упоминается, но скорее о смысловом значении слова, а не о грамматике. А простой российский пользователь уверен, что форма "сот" архаичная и неправильная. http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2598316-neskolko-sot-ili-soten--kak-pravilno.html

Comment: Ну из ссылки нельзя сделать вывод,что простой народ уверен, форма "сот" архаичная и неправильная.

Answer (score 4):

Слово **сто** в значении существительного ("количество 100", "сотня") употребляется только в косв. пад. мн. ч. обычно в сочетании с числительными *много и несколько*:

*род. п. **сот*** — несколько сот рублей, несколько сот участников;
*дат. п. **стам*** — нескольким стам рублей, нескольким стам участников;
*тв. п. **стами*** — с несколькими стами рублей, с несколькими стами союзников;
*предл. п. **о стах*** — много сведений о нескольких стах деятелей, о нескольких стах союзников.
([**Н.Еськова, Словарь трудностей русского языка. Ударение. Грамматические формы**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=vFimCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA389&lpg=PA389&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%9D.%20%D0%95%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=wlJkwhCd1-&sig=-KToU-3cif8YZFETlrv8dEdm7V0&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7k_yAsK7VAhWEd5oKHQYKCjAQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%9D.%20%D0%95%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&f=false))

Хотя [***Толковый словарь Ушакова***](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1043682) (1935-1940) и относит формы "ста, сот, стам, стами, стах" к разговорным,  [***грамота.ру***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD&limitstart=0) на этом акцента не делает (как и ***не "связывает" только с деньгами***):

***Вопрос*** № 208814
Здравствуйте! Несколько СОТ/СОТЕН тысяч человек? Спасибо!
**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Корректны оба варианта. Лучше: несколько сот тысяч человек.

***Вопрос*** № 214129
Как корректно: "несколько сот пользователей" или "несколько сотен пользователей"?
**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Оба варианта верны.